# Search Input slide out on button hover CSS3?

Tags: jquery, css, input, hover

I managed to get the `input` field to slide out when hovering over the "Search" text within the `input` box. BUT I'd rather have the slide out animation on hover with the "GO" button (submit as well).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yAv7/2/)

I wanted to change the `.search input  {width:80px;}` to `30px` so that the `input` field is hidden until the search button is hovered, but I am not sure how to make only the button trigger this animation.

Comment: is there any option to use JQuery?

Comment: I'd like to try and use css only :/ @usman

Comment: just so your comment, I'll leave my answer up in case its useful to someone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this mate: http://jsfiddle.net/7yAv7/10/

What i did was change the `.search input:hover` selector into `.search:hover input`.

This means if you hover over any part of the .search container, the input should animation out.

Not 100% what you wanted but hopefully it helps as a starting point.

Comment: Is there anyway to make the animation stop where the search criteria stops? say someone searched for "Watermelons" can the animation stop at the end of the word so that the text they searched for is still visible when they press enter or click the go button? Hope that makes sense...

Comment: might there also be a way to make the input field slide out on click? @clarkpan

Comment: If you wish to do the other two things you'd need to use javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would use jQuery's hover like so:

```
 $('.srch_btn').hover(function(){
     $('.search input').css('width', '200px');
 },
 function(){
      $('.search input').css('width', '30px');
 });​
```

Comment: Thank You, I'll use this if no other answers are posted.

Comment: I tried this method but now the input field does not slide to the left. Instead it slides to the right. New fiddle// http://jsfiddle.net/SBSAL/

Comment: And for some reason on the actual site the button doesn't trigger the animation. I have the latest jquery set in the header too. What might be the problem here?

Comment: make sure that u have added the proper jquery plugin file

Comment: I have this for jquery // `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in css only by setting the opacity to 0 for the inactive state :

```
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
-moz-opacity: 0;
-khtml-opacity: 0;
-webkit-opacity: 0;
opacity: 0;
```

Working demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/7yAv7/7/

EDIT : when only hovering the go button : http://jsfiddle.net/7yAv7/8/

Comment: I'd like for the input field to slide out only when the "GO" button is hovered...